# xlsxwriter charting issue when using time as the x-axis

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Taking a quick example:

```
Col A        Col B
01:24:12     10
05:23:12     11
```

What I'd like to happen is the x-axis should use the times as the category label but instead it always defaults to 00:00:00 so in the chart the x-axis is all 00:00:00.

To setup the x-axis I use:

```
ctChart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Time', 'name_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': True}, 'num_font': {'italic': True}, 'date_axis': True, 'num_format': 'hh:mm:ss'})
```

Then to insert data:

```
timeFormat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm:ss', 'align': 'left'})
row = 1
for t in ctTime:
    ctWorksheet.write_datetime(row, 0, t, timeFormat)               
    row += 1
ctChart.add_series({'name': 'Power Data','categories': ['Power Data',1,0,len(ctTime),0], 'values': ['Power Data',1,1,len(ctList),1], 'line': {'color': 'red'}})
```

Interestingly, if I remove the 'num_format' from the set_x_axis command then it changes from 00:00:00 to 1,2,3,4 etc.  Seemingly the add_series command isn't recognozing that I want to use time indexing for the x-axis.  When in Excel and using the created workbook if I select a sample of A1:B2 and just hit 'line graph' it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you convert this to a complete working example so I can run it and see what is wrong. Or else submit a github issue (with a complete working example).

Comment: Ok, I'll add the relevant code here.

Comment: Well... When I moved the code over and made small adjustments to make the code work all of a sudden time indexing is working.  SO, I'll delete this question and just concentrate hard on what changed.  Thanks again for your attention!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept answers to your questions if they provide a solution.